# Windows 8 Store App (C#) requireAdministrator in manifest not working

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to run this line of code to disable a device (found in Device Manager) in a Windows 8 Store App (C#):

`bool result = Native.SetupDiCallClassInstaller(Native.DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, hDevInfo, ptrToDevInfoData);`

The result returns "false" meaning it could not disable the device.  I know this line of code might need Administrator privileges to run, so I made a manifest file with this line:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

I added this Post-build event command line:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\mt.exe" -manifest "$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).exe.manifest" -updateresource:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe;#1"`

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Windows Store Applications cannot require administrator priviliages.

Comment: I'm not interested in selling my app in the Windows Store, is it possible to make a touch application (Metro Style UI) using C# that can elevate to Administrator?

Comment: Doesn't matter....Windows Store Applications cannot request administrator priviliages.

Comment: Is there a way to disable devices without administrator privileges (e.g. sound card)?

Comment: Store apps cannot mess with devices, period.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (If you are not bothered about it getting in the store) is to create a normal windows service that can do what you want, then get your metro app to talk to it (Loop back is normally disabled, but since it's not going into the store this won't be an issue).

Comment: I suppose I could use the debugging tools for loopback here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx#enable_loopback_for_network_access

Comment: Exactly. That should let you achieve what you want.